# Run windows program with wine and root privileges

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, wine

I know that is not recommended but i have a windows program that need root privileges to be run. (uses wpacp to read ethernet interfaces).

If I run wine myprogram.exe my program tell me that I don't have permission to read interfaces)

But If i run wine as sudo, wine tell me that .wine is not owned by you.

Any solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. [Super User](http://superuser.com/) is a better choice.

Comment: hmn.. try logging in as root then retry.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is a software question, and not a programming question. You may get more help on [su].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to run wine with sudo you got to have a wineprefix owned by the root user.

Running:

`sudo chown root ~/.wine`

would solve this particular problem but i'd recommend against doing that, since then you won't be able to use wine as a normal user.

A better alternative could be to make a second wineprefix owned by the root user with:

`sudo WINEPREFIX=~/.wine_root winecfg`

(use default location, or provide an alternative)

Then you can just run the program with

`sudo WINEPREFIX=~/.wine_root wine /path/to/your/program.exe`

Although this can be done, running wine with sudo is pretty dangerous so you may want to avoid it at all if possible.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Comment: To undo command that lets you run wine from root and return directory ownership to user, with normal user account logged-in run `sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.wine`.